# Why function with switch statement doesn't need return

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, return, switch-statement

```
enum MyEnum
{
    A,
    B,
}

MyEnum Foo(int i)
{
    MyEnum mx;
    switch(i)
    {
    case 1:
        {
            mx = A;
        }break;
    case 2:
        {
            mx = B;
        }break;
    default:
        {
            throw std::exception("ERROR");
        }
    }
}

int Main()
{
    MyEnum myEnum = Foo(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Without 'return' in Foo( ), This code can be compiled and run in VS2010. Is it compiler bug?

[VS2010 screenshot](https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-snc6/281556_503323443019436_839943479_n.jpg) to confirm that it can be run

Comment: *warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]* http://liveworkspace.org/code/3898ddcf0e5b69eb23763ddf2ba56f51

Comment: No, this is a bug in your code and your development practices by not compiling on the highest warning levels.

Comment: Thanks for all comment,

The root cause is **default** case throw an exception, then compiler see it as an valid exit point.

If i add some code after **switch case**, compiler report `warning C4715: 'Foo' : not all control paths return a value`.

If i remove **default**, or doesn't return or throw in **default**, compiler report `error C4716: 'Foo' : must return a value`.

Comment: @JohnDibling: yep, my fault about warning level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not a compiler bug. A missing return doesn't require a diagnostics from the compiler (but the compiler might emit one), and it leads to **undefined behavior** - anything can happen.

Comment: A function without a return statement is perfectly valid, regardless of return type, if the function never returns. What's not valid is reaching the closing } of the function (with perhaps a few exceptions that you shouldn't rely on), but an unconditional call to abort() at the end of the function, for example, is also valid. I know that's what you meant, but the subtle difference is significant in that it explains why compilers can't/shouldn't just issue an unconditional warning if there's no return statement.

Comment: @BeersonicPasagorn if no return is there, it's easier for the compiler to tell the function never returns. However, I don't think a diagnostics is required even then.

Comment: Just remove **default** or **throw exception**, then compiler can report `return is missing`

Comment: @BeersonicPasagorn I know, I'm just saying it's not required to.

Comment: +1. The standard writers know better than to require compilers to report a diagnostic. This is essentially the halting problem.

Comment: According to [Microsoft's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/k68ktdwf(v=vs.100).aspx): "_When the flow of control exits the block enclosing the function definition, the result is the same as it would be if a return statement without an expression had been executed. This is invalid for functions that are declared as returning a value._"

IMO such invalid behaviour should trigger a compiler error.